# An elegant/efficient way of filling an struct vector with inner vectors

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Is there any elegant or efficient way of filling a struct (this struct)

```
struct doublePolygon{
std::vector<double> x, y;};
```

I have something like this:

```
int main(void){

   std::vector<doublePolygon> Poly;
   doublePolygon Poly_tmp;

   Poly_tmp.x = { 0,    23.37,  50.24,  31.26,  34.57,  1.46,   4.69,   0 };        // x
   Poly_tmp.y = { 0,    11.91,  0,      -21.39, -32.22, -26.31, -13.17, 0 };        // y
   Poly.push_back(Poly_tmp);
   Poly_tmp.x.clear();
   Poly_tmp.y.clear();
   Poly_tmp.x = { 42.19,  35.69,  29.76,  34.46,  42.19 };      // x
   Poly_tmp.y = { -4.26, 2.34, -5.2, -11.87, -4.26 };       // y
   Poly.push_back(Poly_tmp);
}
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Define _efficient_ please.

Comment: Google `std::initializer_list` and _aggregate/uniform initialisation_. Suffice it to say that with C++11 or later, you can just do `doublePolygon dp{ {x, y, z,  /* ... */}, {p, q, u,  /* ... */} };`

Comment: Those parens `{` and `}` comes in double packages at a cheap price: `{ {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, combining two basic tenets of C++11:

- Use **uniform initialisation**, in this case a.k.a. **aggregate initialisation**, to address `struct` members `a` and `b` directly (i.e. without having to write a custom constructor) during initialisation;
- use the **`std::initializer_list`** constructor of `vector` to supply arbitrarily long lists of elements to each member `a` and `b`, including during uniform initialisation;
- and then do the same for your `vector` of `struct`s

Here is how it would look. I'm using placeholders to indicate where you'd put your `double`s, so we can focus on the concepts rather then specific data.

```
std::vector<doublePolygon> vdp{ // calls vector( std::initializer_list<doublePolygon> )
    { // aggregate-initialise outer vector element [0]
        {a, b, c, d, /* ... */}, // vector( std::initializer_list<double> ) for x
        {e, f, g, h, /* ... */}  // " for y
    },
    { // outer vector element [1]
        {i, j, k, l, /* ... */}, // x
        {m, n, o, p, /* ... */}  // y
    }, /* etc... */
};
```

So, that's constructing an outer vector with an `std::initializer_list` of `struct doublePolygon`s, each itself aggregate-initialised by calling its members' constructors with `std::initializer_list`s of `double`s.

Note the compiler has special knowledge of `std::initializer_list` and creates one in relevant contexts from a `{bunch, of, elements}` where it can deduce a common, non-narrowing type. If you have special type needs or just want to, you can declare explicitly: `std::initializer_list<TemplateType>{the, things}`. Also note it's only for initialising with, not a general-purpose container! It maps onto a temporary array that only lives within its *full-expression*.

You can research for plenty pre-existing info on both of these concepts as they are very widely discussed and demonstrated. Probably because of how much they improved the language!

Comment: @SergioPertuz You're welcome, and thanks for letting me/us know it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a constructor to the struct and get:

```
struct doublePolygon {
std::vector<double> x, y;
doublePolygon(const std::vector<double>& x, const std::vector<double>& y)
    : x(x), y(y) { }
};
```

and then initialization would be (in C++11)

```
std::vector<doublePolygon> Poly = {
    doublePolygon({ 0,    23.37,  50.24,  31.26,  34.57,  1.46,   4.69,   0 },
                  { 0,    11.91,  0,      -21.39, -32.22, -26.31, -13.17, 0 }),
    doublePolygon({ 42.19,  35.69,  29.76,  34.46,  42.19 },
                  { -4.26, 2.34, -5.2, -11.87, -4.26 })
};
```

Comment: Adding a constructor is redundant because uniform initialisation allows the members to be constructed directly. The compiler-generated default ctor will be just as good, or possibly better, than this. And it avoids typing.